# Adjust label positions in XIB for iOS 8 UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tableViewCell` `XIB` in which there are several labels.Initially I adjusted the positions of rightmost labels in XIB itself.This wasn't a problem until I upgraded to iOS 8 and thus, iPhone 6 simulator.Now the rightmost labels are placed far more inside the cell.(more to the left ie).I tried setting the frames of these labels in `cellForRow` method but it doesn't seem to work.Where exactly do we need to do this?

Here is what I did in 'cellForRow'

```
    cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin; //didn't change anything


    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 96);
    [cell setFrame:frame];
    [cell.fare setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width-50, 10, 10, 10)]; //rightmost uilabel in cell
```

But the positions of these labels are still with respect to cell size of previous standard size ie 320 width.Now I am not using `autoLayout` , so I have set the struts and spring for `tableView` to occupy the entire width of view. So the `tableView` occupies the whole width but it doesn't seem to do the same for cell .

Comment: AutoResizingMask. Try it please.

Comment: The problem -- probably -- is that self.view.frame isn't correct at the point in time when you're using it. I know it seems daunting, but... try autolayout-- it works all this stuff out automagically once you get the hang of it. :-)

Comment: Autolayout might take more time :-).So I was thinking if this can be solved the easy way.

Comment: @icodes auto layout is the easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the size of the cell yourself, the OS does that for you. 
As the iPhone 6 has a wider screen, make sure that the labels are right-aligned in your XIB, with either auto-resizing (flexible left-margin for the label), or constraints (fixed distance to container right edge). Don't fix them in place.

Comment: Althogh I have just one question.I did this------>NSLog(@"cell width : %f",cell.frame.size.width); which is giving me 320.00?

Comment: @icodes That depends on where you did that. If you have defined the cell with frame width of 320 in the XIB, then it will initially have width 320, which is changed to the proper size before the cell is laid out and displayed (basically before layoutSubviews is called).

Answer (score 0):

Apply AutoresizingMask

```
cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Comment: have you disabled autolayout?\

Comment: it shows a black screen around right side and bottom of table view. guess I need more constraints to set it right